# Matplotlib: how to give xticks values from a list

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xticks = ['A','B','C']
Scores = np.array([[5,7],[4,6],[8,3]])
colors = ['red','blue']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(Scores,bins=3,density=True,histtype='bar',color=colors)
plt.show()
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: histogram of code]

I have two questions:

1. How can I make the height of bars represent the values in `Scores` e.g. the left most red column should be of height 5 and left most blue column should be of height 7, and so on.
2. How can I assign values across x-axis from `xticks` list e.g. the left two columns should have 'A' written under them, the next two 'B' and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confound a histogram with a bar plot. Here you want a bar plot. If you want to use pandas, this is going to be very easy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

xticks = ['A','B','C']
Scores = np.array([[5,7],[4,6],[8,3]])
colors = ['red','blue']
names = ["Cat", "Dog"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pd.DataFrame(Scores, index=xticks, columns=names).plot.bar(color=colors, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If using matplotlib alone, it's slighlty more complicated, because each column needs to be plotted independently,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xticks = ['A','B','C']
Scores = np.array([[5,7],[4,6],[8,3]])
colors = ['red','blue']
names = ["Cat", "Dog"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(len(Scores))
ax.bar(x-0.2, Scores[:,0], color=colors[0], width=0.4, label=names[0])
ax.bar(x+0.2, Scores[:,1], color=colors[1], width=0.4, label=names[1])
ax.set(xticks=x, xticklabels=xticks)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How can I give custom labels in the first figure instead of 0 and 1?

Comment: 0 and 1 are the column names of your dataframe. Is your question how to name columns in pandas?

Comment: Yes, I would like to name columns, but for a `numpy.ndarray` object since `Scores` is of that type.

Comment: Ok, I updated both solutions with how to get a legend.

Answer (score 2):

You already did a lot of the work for the histogram. Now you just need some bar plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xticks = ['A','B','C']
Scores = np.array([[5,7],[4,6],[8,3]])
colors = ['red','blue']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Width of bars
w=.2

# Plot both separately
ax.bar([1,2,3],Scores[:,0],width=w,color=colors[0])
ax.bar(np.add([1,2,3],w),Scores[:,1],width=w,color=colors[1])

# Assumes you want ticks in the middle
ax.set_xticks(ticks=np.add([1,2,3],w/2))

ax.set_xticklabels(xticks)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you tell what [1,2,3] represent? And any neater way to replace [1,2,3] by.

Comment: Before adding ticks, you need to have a location for them in a numerical range for the start of the ticks. If you have more than 3 items, you can always do `np.arange(0,numer_of_items,1)`. Just make sure that your `xticks` has the same number of elements. (Where `number_of_items` is the length of your np array.)

Answer (score 0):

`plt.xticks(range(0, 6), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'))` would work to answer question part 2 I believe. I'm not sure about the heights, as I haven't made histograms.